# Inserting data to ntext xml column (Cannot call methods on ntext error)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table include XML column with `ntext` data type.

```
CREATE TABLE #Testing 
(
    Id int identity,
    content ntext
)

INSERT INTO #Testing
VALUES (N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data <BankAcc><Bankname value="TEST Qərib Bank "/><AccNum value="TEST1221"/></BankAcc>
</Data>')
```

I want to insert this data `<Owner value="Qərib"/>` into existing `ntext` data type xml column with code below

```
 update #Testing
 set content.modify(N'insert <Owner value="Qərib"/> into (/Data)[1]')
```

but I get an error:

> Msg 258, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
> Cannot call methods on ntext

So I try to use cast

```
update #Testing
 set cast(content as varchar(max)).modify(N'insert <Owner value="Qərib"/> into (/Data)[1]')
```

then I got this error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
> Incorrect syntax near '('.

Any solution ?

Comment: Why are you *still* using `ntext`? It's been deprecated for *at least* 15 years. It's long past time you start using `nvarchar(MAX)`.

Comment: Also, `ntext` isn't `xml`. if you want to use `xml` functions on a value it needs to be the `xml` data type. Don't store your XML data in a 15 year deprecated data type and use the appropriate `xml` data type.

Comment: @Larnu i know and understand you.but structure made with ntext data type.Its legacy.i dont need to change any structure.the xml data located in ntext data type column..

Comment: Even legacy applications should have been updated by now. Like I said, `ntext` has been deprecated for *at least* 15 years.

Answer (score 0):

convert your data type to nvarchar(max), varchar(max) or varbinary(max)

> IMPORTANT! ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=The%20ISO%20synonym%20for%20ntext%20is%20national%20text.&text=Variable%2Dlength%20non%2DUnicode%20data,storage%20is%20still%202%2C147%2C483%2C647%20bytes.)

If it is proper xml then XML data type will fit best

Comment: For what the OP wants to achieve, they will **need** to use the `xml` datatype. You can't use XML functions, like `modify` against a string data type (such as an `nvarchar`).

Comment: i have added above @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu

Comment: ``cast(content as xml).modify` but I am not sure If you can cast from ntext to xml. you may need additional operation